# What is the eviction policy for AWS API Gateway Cache?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Can someone please tell me (supported by some documentation) how the API Gateway Cache evicts items when it reaches its maximum size?

The only information I could find was https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246149 which is just an opinion on a forum post. So I am uncomfortable with assuming that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Forum information is correct. ApiGateway cache use LRU eviction strategy.